# Is it possible to generate typescript code from flowtype code?

Tags: typescript, flowtype, definitelytyped

Since flow and typescript are quite similar in many aspects I have wondered, if it is possible to generate typescript declaration files from flow code. Or the other way generate flow code from typescript.

So does anyone know if this is even possible?

And if it is possible, is there an existing tool?

Answer (score -1):

Yes but the feature is still in development see this comment for usage https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3168#issuecomment-271559249

Comment: I realised that the question title was not pricise enough. What i am searching for is a possibility to translate flow-code to typescript-code and vise versa

Answer (score -1):

I just found this project that does this, but only generates Flow definitions from Typescript: https://github.com/joarwilk/flowgen.